# Hibernate + PostgreSQL throws an Exception: Unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, postgresql, maven

I write a java maven project for restful `webservice` using `jersey + hibernate` and having below `error`:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.MappingException:
>   Unknown entity:  org.asad.dto.logindetail
>
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:419)
>
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:
>       381)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:
>       221)

**hibernate.cfg.xml File:**

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC

        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"

        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>


    <session-factory>


        <!-- Database connection settings -->

        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Drive</property>

        <property 
    name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/logindb</property>

    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>

        <property name="connection.password">project</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->

        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>


        <!-- SQL dialect -->

        <property 
    name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->

    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>


        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <propertyname="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->

        <mapping class="org.asad.dto.logindetail"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

The table name is "logindetail".

**Database Class:**

```
 @Entity
     @Table (name = "logidetail")  public class logindetail {

    @Id

    int userId;

    String name;

    String password;


    public void setUserId(int i){

        this.userId = i;

    }

    public int getUserId(){

        return userId;

    }

    public void setName(String name){

        this.name  = name;

    }

    public String getName(){

        return name;

    }

    public void setPassword(String pass){

        this.password = pass;

    }

    public String getPassword(){

        return password;

    }}
```

**Main Class:**

```
 package org.asad.login.login.loginservice; 

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.management.Query;

import javax.validation.Validation;

import javax.validation.Validator;

import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;

import org.asad.dto.logindetail;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configurationimport org.hibernate.classic.Session;

public class LoginService{

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    Session session = null;

    public String getDatabaseUser(){

        logindetail user = null;

        String name=null;try{

        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        user = (logindetail)session.get(logindetail.class, 2);

        name = user.getName();

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();

    }catch(Exception e){

       e.printStackTrace();

     }

    return name;

        }}
```

now this error is coming `java.lang.NullPointerException`
anyone can help me to eliminate this error i will b thankful :)

Comment: Please don't use lowercase names for class names. But that's not the problem. I do not see a package directive above your class code. But you have used a package 'org.asad.dto.' in the hibernate configuration. That might be the problem. If it is then, put the class in the resp. package.

Comment: Check the package of `logindetail` is the same like provided in <mapping class="..." />.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer ok i will take care about class names in future . The package is put in the class but still the error.

Comment: @barthel yes the package is same as the  provided in the mapping class.

Comment: Tell us about the action that throws this exception and provide the **full** stacktrace and Hibernate version. Also switch loglevel of hibernate to debug/trace will more explain the error.

Comment: And of course, you've not only added the package directive, bult also moved your .java file to the corresponding package directory. `$SRC/org/asad/dto. Just an idea ;-)

Comment: @barthel  SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.asad.dto.logindetail

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer yes i moved the java file in org.asad.dto package

Comment: Can you try with : `user = (logindetail)session.get(logindetail.class, new Integer(2));` And also change your import `import org.hibernate.classic.Session;` to `import org.hibernate.Session;`

Comment: Also remove the line `session.getTransaction().commit();` as it is not needed in case of get operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if you imported correct `@Entity` annotation.

As  `@Entity` comes under two packages one is `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` and other one with  `javax.persistence.Entity`.

Use `javax.persistence.Entity` to annotate your entity beans. Don't import `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`.

Comment: it works but data is not comming from database showinng 204 no content

Comment: Post your main class content, then only one can suggest something.

Comment: @Asad I uv this answer because it might help other developers which have a similiar problem. And it shows you and me ;-) how important it is to provide a complete class file - with package and imports. Lucky you, that Arpit has so much experience to gues the answer correctly.

Comment: @Arpit i add the class see  and suggest me

Comment: @Asad the `logindetail` entity class instead. And **please** check the format and layout before save the question.